# Proguard returned with error code 1

Tags: proguard

Hello I want to apply proguard to secury my application but while doing this following errors are generated, I don't know how to handle it, so please help me, any suggestion related to it will be appreciated.

```
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid instruction offset [95] in code fragment at level 0
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.classfile.editor.CodeAttributeComposer.remapInstructionOffset(CodeAttributeComposer.java:669)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.classfile.editor.CodeAttributeComposer.visitExceptionInfo(CodeAttributeComposer.java:486)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.classfile.editor.CodeAttributeComposer.appendException(CodeAttributeComposer.java:229)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.classfile.editor.ExceptionInfoAdder.visitExceptionInfo(ExceptionInfoAdder.java:65)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.exceptionsAccept(CodeAttribute.java:153)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.optimize.peephole.MethodInliner.copyCode(MethodInliner.java:309)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.optimize.peephole.MethodInliner.visitCodeAttribute(MethodInliner.java:159)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:79)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:91)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:439)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:281)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:114)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:560)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:325)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:114)
[2011-07-28 14:42:17 - Registration]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:499)
```

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some lines missing from your log (like the version number). Your ProGuard configuration would also help figuring out what is going wrong.

Generally, the message points to a bug in ProGuard. You should check if the latest version solves the problem (ProGuard 4.6 at this time of writing).